# c# regular expression to Search a sting

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I want to search a string **PQR** (case insensitive) **ABC XYZ** (case sensitive) sequentially in a string. What will be the regular expression for that?

e.g

- this is **pqr** test string **ABC XYZ** => IsMatch() should return true
- **PQRanother** example **ABC XYZ** test => IsMatch() should return true
- this **PQR** is another test **abc xyz** => IsMatch() should return false
  since abc xyz is not in uppercase
- **ABC XYZ** test string **pqr** => IsMatch() should return false since strings are not in sequence
- hello **pqr** test **ABC** & **XYZ** => IsMatch() should return false
  since strings ABC XYZ does not exist.
- hello123 **pqr** \n\n\n(new line) test ABC XYZ bla bla bla => should return true

Also, I want to learn regular expression, please suggest me any website to study regular expression.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if pattern are really so simple, you better use IndexOf and specify the case options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
(?i)pqr.*(?-i)ABC XYZ
```

`(?i)` means case insensitive; `(?-i)` means case sensitive.

EDIT: Use single-line mode if this can span lines

```
Regex.Matches(input, "(?i)pqr.*(?-i)ABC XYZ", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. but ABC XYZ can be on new line. It should retuen true if ABC XYZ is on new line

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
[pP][qQ][rR].*ABC XYZ
```

- `[pP]` matches p or P, same for `[qQ]` and `[rR]`,
- `.*` matches any character (`.`), any number of times (`*`), i.e., there can be stuff between pqr and ABC which is ignored,
- `ABC XYZ` matches the literal string `ABC XYZ`.

For .NET regular expressions, you could start with the introductory page, which contains a few examples:

- [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)